# Will this cause a browser memory leak?

Tags: javascript, html

I create a couple divs with an `onclick` event on them as children of 'parentDiv'. In the future, I set `parentDiv.innerHTML = 'xyz'` where xyz is more divs with `onclick` events, which replace the old ones.

My question: will any browsers leak memory because I did not remove the `onclick` events of the the old div's before removing them from the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading up on [memory leaks](http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html) as explained by Douglas Crockford. The article gives you detailed examples of memory leaks and even a nice purge function allowing you to overcome the issues associated with them. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove them from the DOM then any event handlers *should* be removed from them as well and not cause a leak.

Douglas Crockford has some excellent writing on [JavaScript Memory Leaks](http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html). Well worth the read.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is up to the browser to manage.  As objects are removed, the browser will (or at least should) free up associated memory.  I wouldn't bank on it though.

In any case, unless you are doing this thousands of times, I wouldn't expect it to be an issue.

Comment: Crap.  Well, sounds like this is a good project for some research.  :-D  If you wouldn't mind posting the page, I would be happy to profile it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually no.

However, if your onclick handler happens to be closure which references the HTML element it is attached to, then it could leak in some browsers.

Have a look at this guide I wrote for more details on JavaScript memory leaks and how to find and fix them: http://www.vladalexandruionescu.com/2012/08/javascript-memory-leaks.html. That should clear things up for you.